# Why didn't the Indominus rex utilise her camouflage ability more often?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world

*Indominus rex*, the main antagonist introduced in Jurassic World, was demonstrated to be able to blend herself quite well to her surroundings, making her practically invisible to the naked eye in the forest.

This ability was proven to be ultimately useful for eliminating (or should I say *hunting down*) her aggressors *exclusively* in the scene where she literally ripped a battalion of trained men complete with weapons and protections apart.

It is also known that the *I. rex* was notably smarter than most of the dinosaurs (probably because she was part 'raptor). This was also proven in the scene where she fooled the guards thinking that she had escaped by making fake claw marks and lowering her body temperature, so that she'd be invisible to the thermal camera that constantly monitored her enclosure.

Given those facts, shouldn't she be aware of how powerful her camouflage ability could've been and how it could've helped her to become a better predator?

Had she utilized this ability more, she could've fled the battle scene with Owen and the rest of the ACU units (the one where the Raptors betrayed Owen) quicker and with less damage done to her part.

Heck, she had probably won the battle with Rexie had she opted to camo between the park ruins - considering the fact that they were battling at night time.

So.. *why*? Why does a dinosaur created to be the ultimate killing machine with all the brawn and the brains needed to do so fail to see her own potential, despite her mature age and formerly demonstrated intelligence?

Comment: Because she's a schmuck.

Comment: Not if you consider the fact that she fooled a group of experts (in their fields) without even knowing about the world outside of her enclosure.

Comment: The iRex's escape is a bit of a plot hole for me: this is a creature which the movie repeatedly tells us is completely unique and doesn't know its place in the world...yet it manages to perfectly use it's Predator camouflage twice: once to escape the enclosure, and once to surprise the guards.  As far as we can tell, these are the only two times this animal has used this ability *in its entire life* (as the scientists who monitor it were unaware of this attribute)...yet it manages it flawlessly.  Ditto for the "masking body heat" superpower (it also instinctively knew how IR cameras worked).

Comment: @Liesmith now that's something I think we could both agree on. It looks like the scriptwriter has made the iRex overly powerful - so powerful to the point where if she had unleashed her full potential just like when she made her escape, there would be no way to beat her. It's quite a shame though, as this move was never necessary at all; as her camouflage and body-thermal controlling capability seemed to be there just so they could make some sense to her breakout. They could've remove those traits from the iRex and thought of another way of her escape instead.

Comment: @ridsatrio Yeah, I was hoping it would do something genuinely clever, rather than pull a Golden Age Superman and just make up superpowers until it wins.

Comment: Hmm, let me just ask her...

Comment: [two minutes later] "Arhrhghghhhg, she's loose, she's after me... AAARRGGHGRRHG!!, MY LEGS!! ROAAAR".

Comment: [two minutes later] Yeah, she said she just didn't feel like it. Also, do you have a band-aid and some repair-o-limb? On a completely unrelated note: you may want to find some cover.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The iRex™ only uses its camo abilities on four occasions; in the paddock (to hide from the sensors and cameras), when hunting the Ankylosaurs, when hiding from the helicopter gunship and before encountering the raptors.

In each of the cases when the Indominus rex uses these skills the following conditions are met;

- **It's in deep jungle**
- **It's trying to be stealthy.**

When *actively* under attack by a ground-based predator, concentrating on camouflaging itself, in unfamiliar surroundings, with colours that aren't generally found in nature is probably extremely hard to do and borders on stupid if it gets it wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Only battle it could lose, was against trex. It's intelligence and camouflage was surprising effect against humans and it must have known it, passed every human barrier easily. Trex wouldn't care about its intelligence, it just needed a movement.

It could have used something like this

[image]

on trex but velociraptors wounded its back badly before, having pain and damaged skin would be hard to use this ability. Also Owen shot it many times with a Marlin Model 1895SBL from below. Its skin was like colander and bloody, add stress of "being attacked by every predator around", a diversion of mind. Stress management is important too. Without it, you can't even control your yourself under high depression let alone camouflaging.

I wonder if it released ink into the lake when mosasaurus caught it, or some poisonous sweat as being a frog.

Answer (score -1):

She was also proving her abilities. And the camouflage is useful only against humans.

The velociraptors can smell her tracks in the jungle. But the camouflage can was useful against Rexy (I know that T rexes have a good sense of smell, but Rexy has a poor one. According to Jurassic Pedia, in JP Universe, the male T rexes are the hunters and protectors in rex families, and the males possess a very superior sense of smell, much better than females, and this is seen in TLW, the Buck T-rex is the one who tracks the blood. His mate is not).

So, her camouflage is only useful against humans. If she is camouflaging against dinosaurs, they can smell her, especially carnivores, as velociraptors (this is seen in the movie).

If instead of fighting a female T rex as Rexy, the Indominus rex fought against a male T rex, the camouflage can be completely useless, because he can smell her tracks, or smell her nearly, found her by her scent and be able to bite her or even kill her.